# Changing OCaml's gcc after installation

Tags: gcc, ocaml

I installed OCaml via OPAM, and by default it uses `gcc` as the command to compile `.c` files. For instance, if I run `ocamlopt -verbose file.c`, I obtain:

```
+ gcc -Wall -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REENTRANT -g  
  -fno-omit-frame-pointer -c -I'/home/user/.opam/4.02.1+fp/lib/ocaml' 'test.c'
```

I'd like to change the GCC binary that is used by OCaml, for instance to replace it with `gcc-5.1` or `/opt/my-gcc/bin/gcc`.

Is it possible to do so without reconfiguring and recompiling OCaml? I suppose I could add a `gcc` alias to a directory in the `PATH`, but I'd prefer a cleaner solution if there is one.

To check if `gcc` was not chosen based on a textual configuration file (that I could easily change), I searched for occurrences of `gcc` in my `/home/user/.opam/4.02.1+fp` directory, but the only occurrence in a non-binary file that I found was in `lib/ocaml/Makefile.config`, and changing it does nothing for the already-compiled binary.

Comment: What do you want to do, change the c binaries used in the compiler or change the c compiler used for packages? In the former, you need to recompile.

Comment: I want to change the path used by the `ocamlopt` binary to find GCC. I was hoping there might be environment variables or configuration files to change it, but from what you say apparently there aren't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ocamlopt` uses `gcc` for three things. First, for compiling `.c` files that appear on the command line of `ocamlopt`. Second, for assembling the `.s` files that it generates internally when compiling an OCaml source file. Third, for linking the object files together at the end.

For the first and third, you can supply a different compiler with the `-cc` flag.

For the second, you need to rebuild the OCaml compiler.

**Update**

Here's what I see on OS X when compiling a C and an OCaml module with the `-verbose` flag:

```
$ ocamlopt -verbose -cc gcc -o m m.ml c.c 2>&1 | grep -v warning
+ clang -arch x86_64 -c -o 'm.o' \
  '/var/folders/w4/1tgxn_s936b148fdgb8l9xv80000gn/T/camlasm461f1b.s' \
+ gcc -c   -I'/usr/local/lib/ocaml' 'c.c'
+ clang -arch x86_64 -c -o \
  '/var/folders/w4/1tgxn_s936b148fdgb8l9xv80000gn/T/camlstartup695941.o' \
  '/var/folders/w4/1tgxn_s936b148fdgb8l9xv80000gn/T/camlstartupb6b001.s'
+ gcc -o 'm'   '-L/usr/local/lib/ocaml' \
  '/var/folders/w4/1tgxn_s936b148fdgb8l9xv80000gn/T/camlstartup695941.o' \
  '/usr/local/lib/ocaml/std_exit.o' 'm.o' \
  '/usr/local/lib/ocaml/stdlib.a' 'c.o' \
  '/usr/local/lib/ocaml/libasmrun.a'
```

So, the compiler given by the `-cc` option is used to do the compilation of the `.c` file and the final linking. To change the handling of the `.s` files you need to rebuild the compiler. I'm going to update my answer above.

Comment: The [Native compilation manual page](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/native.html) (in which I had searched for 'gcc' instead of 'cc' and missed the relevant option) actually says that option -cc does "use ccomp as the C linker called to build the final executable and as the C compiler for compiling .c source files". That would seem to indicate that step 3 is also be done by the compiler defined in `-cc`. Indeed, if I try `-cc "gcc -m32"` on a 64-bit host, `ld` fails when trying to link 64-bit files produced by ocamlopt with the `gcc -m32` option I gave it.

Comment: (Thanks, I updated my answer to what I now think is correct.)